# Use pug and sass in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, pug

Can I use `pug/jade` and `sass` in `react`?

Actually I love to separate files and I like to categorize codes the way sass and pug can do for me is great.

Is there any way to use pug and sass in react?

Pug example:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en", dir="ltr" , xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" , prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb:http://ogp.me/ns/fb#")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(rel="stylesheet" , href="style.css")
  body
    p.a minim tamen labore cillum aute nulla quis anim anim summis
    ul
      each val in('one','two','three')
        li
          a(href="#",target="_blank")=val
```

Comment: You can do use both pug and react, but then you are mixing two technologies to create DOM content for you. I am not sure what the purpose would be. The ul and li example you are giving could instead be a react list component.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use Scss within your React Component. You have to use an appropriate loader to do so. `sass-loader` it the one you are looking for: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader
This way you can use

`import './styles.scss';`

The markup of your component has to be written in JSX (mix of HTML and JavaScript).
But you could use pug in your entry HTML file, which would include your React bundle.

index.pug

```
body
    #root

script(src="path/to/bundle.js")
```